# Django models: how to get an model object in my views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I have this models

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user, 
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread_notification = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    objects      = ThreadManager()
```

in my model Thread I want to get the object thread_notifications, so I make my views like this

```
def new_notification_thread(request):
    thread_notifier = Thread.objects.filter(pk=1)
    thread_notifier.thread_notification += 1
    thread_notifier.save()

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [thread_notifier]), safe=False)
```

The problem is that when I run my code I get

```
Thread matching query does not exist.
```

does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thread_notifier = Thread.objects.filter(pk=1)
```

You are having this error becuse the item associated with **id = 1 does not exist/deleted**.So when you try to access a **non existing** item you are being shown error.Try accessing a existing id and you should be good to go.

okay, dont use `filter` method to avoid F() expression.instead do this:

```
thread_notifier = Thread.objects.get(pk=1)
```

It wont give you queryset so you can directly access all attributes.
now just following:

```
thread_notifier.thread_notification += 1
thread_notifier.save()
```

**But you have to use filter method when there are more than 1 items.**

Comment: I am new in django so how can I access to the  existing id?

Comment: if u have a db then use a viewer for it,like sqlite tools and change your desired items id to 1.may be it had been removed for some reason!

Comment: now its giving me this error "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'thread_notification'"

Comment: good.that means previous error is solved.now you are getting new error.let me think

Comment: You can not acces a field from a queryset/list. you have loop thru it to make it break into pieces.i am updating my answer.

Comment: its giving this "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: You have to import F from django.db.models and then use F() expression.

Comment: thread_notifier.F()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'F'

Comment: oh man!dont use F() like this.you will read the documentation or i will post the code here?

Comment: yes can post here how to use F(), I didnt know that F() exist

Comment: check this out.

Comment: You have to use F() later on,so better take a note from django docs.

Comment: yes, but I use get and save and I have two objects with different id´s in my db